# Stackoverflow Error in the GameLayer

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-iphone, stack-overflow

After browsing i got to know that Stackoverflow Error is due to recursive call of a method, this is my code where i'm getting the above error, but not able to solve this.

```
public static GameLayer sharedGameLayer() {
    return sharedGameLayer();
}
```

logcat Error

```
09-16 15:13:30.074: E/AndroidRuntime(1597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 15:13:30.074: E/AndroidRuntime(1597): java.lang.StackOverflowError
09-16 15:13:30.074: E/AndroidRuntime(1597):     at com.ps.GameLayer.sharedGameLayer(GameLayer.java:533)
09-16 15:13:30.074: E/AndroidRuntime(1597):     at com.ps.GameLayer.sharedGameLayer(GameLayer.java:533)
09-16 15:13:30.074: E/AndroidRuntime(1597):     at com.ps.GameLayer.sharedGameLayer(GameLayer.java:533)
09-16 15:13:30.074: E/AndroidRuntime(1597):     at com.ps.GameLayer.sharedGameLayer(GameLayer.java:533)
```

Comment: `Stackoverflow Error is due to too many nested viewgroups` not true ... you're getting SO because you are calling your one method inside the same method

Comment: What do you want to happen here? You are calling a function from itself without an exit, this will happen

Comment: Why is this Q receiving downvotes? It's a fair question even if the error message and the solution are obvious to us.

Answer (score 4):

Your method calls itself recursively, resulting in you running out of stack.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I hope you are joking.

Comment: I just ran out of memory. :)